# Concatenating variables and incremental numbers in python

Tags: python, format, concatenation

I have a list of words, and I want to have a loop that picks a random word from it and concatenates the next number onto that word.

So far I have

```
import random
wordList = ['some', 'choice', 'words', 'here']
for x in range(0, 10):
    word = random.choice(wordList)
    print word %(x)
```

which throws the error "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

I am trying to follow the format of

```
for x in range(0, 10):
    print "number%d" %(x)
```

which succesfully prints

number0
number1
number2
number3
number4
number5
number6
number7
number8
number9

I assume my problem is with the formatting of the string variable, but I can't figure out how to correct it.

Comment: `print word + str(x)`?

Comment: `print '{}{}'.format(word, x)` should work

Comment: What output are you expecting?  The problem is that you use `word` and the formatting string in your `print` statement, but `word` does not include any formatting specification (such as `%d`) for the value of `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Used a more, in my opinion, readable answer based on @Alan Leuthard's comment.

You need to specify where to format inside the string.

```
for x in range(0, 10):
    word = random.choice(wordList)
    print "%s%d" %(word, x)
```

Or if you are looking for a oneliner,

```
for x in range(0, 10):
    print "%s%d" %(random.choice(wordList), x)
```

If you are using Python 2.7+ or 3.x, it is far easier to use braces instead.

```
for x in range(0, 10):
    print("{}{}".format(random.choice(wordList), x))
```

But if you want to use braces in Python 2.6

```
for x in range(0, 10):
    print("{0}{1}".format(random.choice(wordList), x))
```

Comment: You can use braces in Python 2

Comment: @Victor You can use braces in 2.6 but you can't use implicit references, `"{0}{1}".format(...)` should work in 2.6 and 3.6. In 3.6, you can add one and use `f-strings`: `f'{random.choice(wordList)}{x}'`

Answer (score 1):

This means that not all the arguments are being converted in the string. It's because you forgot to add a  "%d" to the end of the string. This should work

```
   In [29]: import random
        ...: wordList = ['some', 'choice', 'words', 'here']
        ...: for x in range(0, 10):
        ...:     word = random.choice(wordList) + "%d"
        ...:     print word %(x)
        ...:
here0
here1
some2
words3
words4
some5
here6
here7
words8
words9
```